# Sliding character inside the circle

Tags: collision-detection, movement

When it comes to rect against rect smooth sliding movement, that is easy.

Something like this will work

```
// this isn't real code, just for you to get the idea
// this is a simple sliding code, not really for a good game
sprite.moveX(5);
if (sprite.touches(wall)){
sprite.moveX(-5)
}
sprite.moveY(5);
if (sprite.touches(wall)){
sprite.moveY(-5)
}
```

EDIT: Link for demonstration https://streamable.com/wf9sn7

This will result in the character sliding against the wall, but only if the wall is rectangle.

How do I deal with circles, especially when the character is inside a circle, and colliding with the circle edges?

Note: This will be used for TurboWarp, so any code as Scratch/Turbowarp code will work, but not required

Answer (score 0):

It is not a slide but collision effect.
In a circle, keep in mind the radius of the circle. If the distance of your object from the center of the circle is smaller than the aforementioned radius, your character is inside the circle.

So if you want to keep a character inside a circular area, you could do this (in the same vein as your sample code):

```
sprite.Move()
if(distance(sprite,circlecenter)>circleradius)
{
    //character is moving outside of circle!
    sprite.undoMove()
}
```

Now it is better to check if the sprite will cross the boundary *before* you move the sprite, if that predicts the sprite will move outside the circle, limit the movement to the edge of the circle instead.

Comment: this will make the character get stuck, not slide

Comment: It is intended as an example how to find the collision, your own example code does the same: moveX by 5 check for the wall undo the move by moving 5 in the opposite direction. There is no sliding in your own code either. If you want to slide your sprite along the perimeter of the circle use the radius to move the sprite and check if it’s left or right from the center.

Comment: Im spliting my X and Y, and if my X movement touches, the X is reset, but the Y remains normal, giving it a look of sliding along wall

Comment: I edited it for more clarity

Comment: I understand what you mean. In the end I think it depends on what you want to happen; Let's say the player stats perfectly in the center- if the player keeps pressing south-east, where does the player end up? Would the player slide down because of south or slide to the right/up because of east? The calculation to see if the wall is hit is simple, it is then a matter of your usecase which direction the sprite should go. Also, if the player is at the edge; how much would you want the player to slide- because that may mean you need to calculate the angle and how much of the circle arc to move.